# Finding $ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{\sin ^4 x} d x-\ln 2 \cdot n^2-\frac{1}{4} \ln n\right)$

Tags: integration, limits

By numerical estimation, I get
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{\sin ^4 x} d x-\ln 2 \cdot n^2-\frac{1}{4} \ln n\right)=\frac{6 \gamma+4 \ln 2+5}{24} .
$$
But I can't prove it yet. I made some attempts：

(1)  We can get
$$
\lim _{y \rightarrow+\infty}\left(\int_0^y \frac{\sin ^4 x}{x} d x-\frac{3}{8} \ln y\right)=\frac{3 \gamma+2 \ln 2}{8} .
$$
And for sufficiently small $c>0$,there is
$$
\frac{x}{\sin ^4 x}-\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{2}{3 x} \leqslant 1, x \in[0, c] .
$$

(2)According to the Riemann Lemma, we have
$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_c^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{\sin ^4 x} d x=\frac{3}{8} \int_c^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x}{\sin ^4 x} d x.
$$

(3) By (1), we have
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^c x \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{\sin ^4 x} d x & \leqslant \int_0^c \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{x^3} d x+\frac{2}{3} \int_0^c \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{x} d x+\int_0^c \sin ^4(n x) d x \\
& \leqslant n^2 \int_0^{n c} \frac{\sin ^4(x)}{x^3} d x+\frac{2}{3} \int_0^{n c} \frac{\sin ^4(x)}{x} d x+c \\
& =n^2\left(\ln 2-\int_{n c}^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^4(x)}{x^3} d x\right)+\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{3}{8} \ln (n c)+\frac{3 \gamma+2 \ln 2}{8}\right)+c+o(1) \\
& =\ln 2 \cdot n^2-\int_c^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{x^3} d x+\left(\frac{1}{4} \ln (n c)+\frac{\gamma+\frac{2 \ln 2}{3}}{4}\right)+c+o(1) 
\end{aligned}
i.e.
$$
\int_0^c x \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{\sin ^4 x} d x  \leqslant\ln 2 \cdot n^2-\int_c^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{x^3} d x+\left[\frac{1}{4} (\ln n +\ln c)+\frac{\gamma+\frac{2 \ln 2}{3}}{4}\right]+c+o(1)
$$

(4) By (2)(3), we have
$$
\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{\sin ^4 x} d x-\ln 2 \cdot n^2-\frac{1}{4} \ln n\right)\leqslant \varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}  (\frac{3}{8} \int_c^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x}{\sin ^4 x} d x-\int_c^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{x^3} d x+\frac{\ln c}{4}+\frac{\gamma+\frac{2 \ln 2}{3}}{4}+c+o(1)).
$$

I want to prove that

$$
\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{3}{8} \int_c^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x}{\sin ^4 x} d x-\int_c^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{x^3} d x+\frac{\ln c}{4})= \frac{5}{24}
,\ c\to 0,$$

and
$$
\varliminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{\sin ^4 x} d x-\ln 2 \cdot n^2-\frac{1}{4} \ln n\right) \geqslant \frac{\gamma+\frac{2 \ln 2}{3}}{4}+\frac{5}{24}.
$$

But I haven't found a way to prove it yet. Can someone give some hints? thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your first line - How does $y$ relate to $n$? Is it $y = \frac{\pi n}{2}$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi sorry,it is a clerical error, which I have revised to the correct expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem we have to prove your formula in the penultimate line :
$$J=\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{3}{8} \int_c^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x}{\sin ^4 x} d x-\int_c^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{x^3} d x+\frac{\ln c}{4})= \frac{5}{24}
,\ c\to 0,\tag{a}$$
Noting that we can use again the Riemann Lemma and get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_c^{\infty} \frac{\sin ^4(n x)}{x^3} d x=\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi\sin^4t\,dt\int_c^\infty\frac{dx}{x^3}=\frac1{2c^2}\cdot\frac38\tag{b}$$
So, our task is to find the asymptotics of $\displaystyle\int_c^\frac\pi2\frac x{\sin^4x}dx$ at $c\to 0$.
$$I(c)=\int_c^\frac\pi2\frac x{\sin^4x}dx\overset{\tan x=t}{=}\int_{\tan c}^\infty\frac{1+t^2}{t^4}\arctan t\,dt$$
Integrating by part several times
$$=-\frac13\frac{\arctan t}{t^3}\,\bigg|_{\tan c}^\infty-\frac1{6t^2(1+t^2)}\,\bigg|_{\tan c}^\infty-\frac{\arctan t}t\,\bigg|_{\tan c}^\infty-\frac13\int_{\tan c}^\infty\frac{dt}{t(1+t^2)^2}+\int_{\tan c}^\infty\frac{dt}{t(1+t^2)}$$
$$=\frac c{3\tan^3c}+\frac c{\tan c}+\frac1{6\tan^2c(1+\tan^2c)}-\frac16\int_{\tan^2c}^\infty\frac{dx}{x(1+x)^2}+\frac12\int_{\tan^2c}^\infty\frac{dx}{x(1+x)}$$
Using $\displaystyle\tan c=c\left(1+\frac {c^2}3+...\right)$
$$I(c)=\frac1{2c^2}-\frac23\ln c-\frac13-\frac2{18}+1+o(c)=\frac1{2c^2}-\frac23\ln c+\frac59+o(c)\tag{c}$$
From (a), (b) and (c) we see that all divergent terms cancel, and we do get
$$\boxed{\,\,J=\frac38\cdot \frac59=\frac5{24}\,\,}$$

Comment: Very thanks. I never note  that we can use Riemann Lemma again. But is there some good idea to prove the last line in the formula?

Comment: I posted a second solution here - https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h3117387_calculate_a_very_difficult_limit The logic is basically the same but, hopefully, every step has a proof. Very interesting problem.

Comment: Yes，and using $\frac x{\sin^4x}-\frac1{x^3}-\frac2{3x}>0$ also can  prove the last line in  formula that I posted.